# WebDav working in IIS Express but not on local IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express, ithit-webdav-server

I am working with the WebDAV Server Engine for .NET component from IT HIT ([link here](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/)).

**What is working:**

- The component is working when I am launching my solution (.NET/C#) in Visual Studio 2017. In that case, I am reaching a mapped drive call "B". "B" allows to access to a server called Vtest (\\Vtest). Below is an extract of the Web.config file from my solution.

```html
<add key="RepositoryPath" value="B:\TEMP" />
```

Both, B:\TEMP and \\Vtest\TEMP are reachable from my computer.

- The component is also working when I publish my solution on my local IIS and I set the value "C:\TEMP" in the web.config file.

**What is not working:**

- The component does not work when I set \\VTest directly inside the key inside the web.config file like this "*key="RepositoryPath" value="\\VTest\TEMP"*"
- The component also does not work when I am publishing the solution with the "B" mapped drive on my local IIS 7.5. The following snippets come from the component log file.

```html
     [17] Could not find item that corresponds to path: 
        [17] HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
        X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.42000 64bit
        X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
        Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length, Allow
        Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
        X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v5.8.3741.0
        Content-Type : application/xml; charset=utf-8
        
        [12] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <d:error xmlns:d="DAV:">
          <d:responsedescription>Item doesn't exist</d:responsedescription>
        </d:error>
```

- When I tried to set my server path (\\Vtest\Temp) in the new webdav project wizard in visual studio, it does not allow me to select the server path (This option requires NTFS file system or Extended Attributes support) (Wizard Screenshot) [New WebDav project wizard in visual studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LEqT.png)

**What I tried since now:**

- I tried to grant maximum permission to the ApplicationPoolIdentity and I am using the pool identity as account for the anonymous authentication. The account profile is also loaded in the application pool properties. These parameters did not help.
- I also tried to set the account (who have maximum permission) instead of IUSR account for the anonymous authentication. I did not change anything.
- I have seen that IIS version on my computer (Windows 7 pro) is 7.5 and VS2017 is using IIS 10, so I tried on a windows server 2016 standard where there is IIS 10. But none of the configurations works.

Does anyone else get this issue with UNC path and WebDav ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently WebDAV server samples with file system back-end provided with IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET do not support network path. You can use only local path with it.

Please find more here: [What is the best way to access remote filestore in ITHit webdav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831414/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-remote-filestore-in-ithit-webdav)