# What is the best way to access remote filestore in ITHit webdav

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am in the middle of implementing a WebDAV server using the ITHit WebDAV engine for .net. The server is a httplistener running as a windows service so using Mapped drive on the service machine is causing problems as it seems services cannot see mapped drive.

I have had some success with using UNC path but the GetExtendedFileAttrjbutes don't seem to work with UNC path ( I am not really using them either but wondering what else might not work).

So the question is, what is the best way of implementing the server which needs to run as a service and access a remote filestore folder?

Are there any recommendations?

Regards
Amar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [WebDAV server samples](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/) with file system back-end provided with IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET do not support network path. You can use only local path with it. The problem is in storing locks, that are saved in extended attributes or NTFS Alternative Data Streams - they are not supported in case of a network path (at least on Windows).

To keep locks you will need some other storage, such as database, some extra files or any other storage. You will reprogram [IFileAsync](https://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.Class1.IFileAsync.htm) interface (implemented in [DavFile.cs](https://github.com/ITHit/WebDAVServerSamples/blob/master/CS/WebDAVServer.FileSystemStorage.AspNetCore/DavFile.cs) and [ExtendedAttributes](https://github.com/ITHit/WebDAVServerSamples/tree/master/CS/WebDAVServer.FileSystemStorage.AspNetCore/ExtendedAttributes) in file system samples).

We try to keep our sample code as simple as possible, that is why we do not support network path, this will make our sample code more complex. We continue to investigate how we can make a simple and viable implementation in our samples to provide such implementation in future updates.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I don't need to use extended attributes so I have removed them. The implementation is working ok with UNC paths. Now we are trying to configure the server behind a load balancer.